# Basic SQL user database

Tags: c#, sql

```
public void AddClient(Client obj){
  try{
      using(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection conn = stock.db.SqlLiteConnection.getSQLLiteConnection()){
      System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
      string sql="insert into Client (email,firstName,lastName,telephone,address,city,state,zip,web) values(@email,@firstName,@lastName,@telephone,@address,@city,@state,@zip,@web)";
      cmd.CommandText = sql;
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", obj.Email);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", obj.FirstName);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", obj.LastName);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", obj.Telephone);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", obj.Address);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", obj.City);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", obj.State);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip", obj.Zip);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@web", obj.Web);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

  }catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

I have couple of questions for the above code

1. Do I have to close connection manually?
2. Do I need to dispose Command object?
3. If exception occurs, do I have to close connection and command
4. How do I enhance this code further?

Comment: You should add relevant tags to get a better responce

Comment: Please explain (4) a bit more...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking explanations are off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here goes:

1. No. You're using `using` which means that the object will be disposed of in the end of the block. As part of the `Dispose()` method, the connection will be closed and its resources released.
2. Not manually, you should open another `using` block to cause the object to `Dispose()` in the end.
3. Thanks to the `using` block, when an exception occurs, the object will be disposed because you're thrown out of the block.
4. "*Enhance*" is vague...

Comment: 2) in your first answer says resources will be released inside code block. Why should I open another "using" to dispose command object

Comment: The resources of the object that is handled by the using block... in your case it's the object referenced by `conn`